# Why won't my function execute correctly based on user input?

Tags: python, function, input

Why won't my function execute correctly based on user input? Below is my script in its entirety including the description. The function defined at the bottom play_again() is what seems to be malfunctioning. Each time I enter 'yes' or 'no' it just displays the user input prompt again.

```py
"""Task 5:
Write a script that plays “guess the number.” Choose the number to be guessed by selecting a random integer in the range 1 to 1000.
Do not reveal this number to the user. Display the prompt "Guess my number between 1 and 1000 with the fewest guesses:". The player inputs a first guess. If the guess is incorrect, 
display "Too high. Try again." or "Too low. Try again." as appropriate to help the player “zero in” on the correct answer, then prompt the user for the next guess. 
When the user enters the correct answer, display "Congratulations. You guessed the number!", and allow the user to choose whether to play again. (10 points). 
"""

import random


def guessing_game():
    number = random.randrange(1, 1001)

guess = int(input('Guess my number between 1 and 1000 with the fewest guesses:')) 
    
while guess != number:   
    if guess >= 1001:
        print("Please enter a number less than or equal to 1000")
        guess = int(input('Guess my number between 1 and 1000 with the fewest guesses:')) 
    elif guess < 1:
        print("Please enter a number greater than or equal to 1")
        guess = int(input('Guess my number between 1 and 1000 with the fewest guesses:')) 
    elif guess > number:
        print("Too high Try again.")
        guess = int(input('Guess my number between 1 and 1000 with the fewest guesses:')) 
    elif guess < number:
        print("Too low. Try again")
        guess = int(input('Guess my number between 1 and 1000 with the fewest guesses:'))
    
        print("Congratulations. You guessed the number", end= " ")
        play_again()


def play_again():
    while True:
        play = input("Would you like to play again? Enter yes or no.")
    if play == 'yes':
        guessing_game()
    elif play == 'no':
        exit()
```

Comment: When I run this code, I get an error at line 9: variable number is not defined.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of minor mistakes.  Here is the corrected code:

```
import random

def guessing_game():
    number = random.randrange(1, 1001)
    guess = int(input('Guess my number between 1 and 1000 with the fewest guesses:'))

    while guess != number:
        if guess >= 1001:
            print("Please enter a number less than or equal to 1000")
            guess = int(input('Guess my number between 1 and 1000 with the fewest guesses:'))
        elif guess < 1:
            print("Please enter a number greater than or equal to 1")
            guess = int(input('Guess my number between 1 and 1000 with the fewest guesses:'))
        elif guess > number:
            print("Too high Try again.")
            guess = int(input('Guess my number between 1 and 1000 with the fewest guesses:'))
        elif guess < number:
            print("Too low. Try again")
            guess = int(input('Guess my number between 1 and 1000 with the fewest guesses:'))

    print("Congratulations. You guessed the number", end=" ")
    play_again()

def play_again():
    while True:
        play = input("Would you like to play again? Enter yes or no.")
        if play == 'yes':
            guessing_game()
        break

guessing_game()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to look at this! I appreciate your help

Comment: You are welcome. Consider refining your code further by defining a  small function that takes and returns user input so that you can call that function anytime you need it instead of rewriting the input code. Also combine your >1000 and <1 conditions into a single condition using the or operator. Good luck on your coding adventures.  Finally don’t forget to accept my answer if you feel it answers your question.